# Vue.js - event handling with on-mouse-click down (and not up)

Tags: event-handling, mouseevent, vue.js, vuejs2

With Vue.js 2 when I add in an @click event to an element and attempt to click something, the event isn't triggered until after I have completed my click (press down -> up).

How do I trigger an event immediate after a mouse click down?

Example:

```
<div @click="foo()">
    Hello
</div>
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can simply use `@mousedown` event on the element, just like `@click`, to handle the `mousedown` event.

```
<button @mousedown="mouseDown">
   mouseDown 
</button>
```

See working fiddle: https://fiddle.jshell.net/mimani/feL03wgd/

Comment: That works, but I also have an `@contextmenu`... which `@mousedown` seems to trigger both left + right clicks.

Comment: @Ben Can you reproduce this in the fiddle.

Comment: https://fiddle.jshell.net/qtso6hqk/

But nevermind; mousedown technically is for either mouse downs. Thanks for the help Saurabh.

Comment: Fiddle is a broken link.

Comment: Just to address the comment about @mousedown being triggered by left and right (and middle) clicks. 
You can use Vue's key modifiers to specify additional conditions to the event.
For restricting mouse click events to left clicks only : '@mousedown.left' & '@mouseup.left'

Comment: ( ignore the single quotes around the last two mouse events. Stackoverflow thought I was trying to reference a user, and says I can only reference one user in a comment )